# print variable value inside string quote

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to print variable value inside string quote

this is my variable

```
var id = $(this).val();
```

how can i print this variable to this string

```
 $('#button_cetak').html('<a href="{{route('report.pdf',[$user->nip,'//this is place i wanna print'])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Cetak</a>');
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

- **1. Make use of JavaScript String Literals**

```
var id = $(this).val();
$('#button_cetak').html(`<a href="{{ route('report.pdf',[$user->nip,'${id}'])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Cetak</a>`);
```

- **2. JavaScript dummy replace**

```
var id = $(this).val();
var url = `<a href="{{ route('report.pdf',[$user->nip,':id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Cetak</a>`;
url = url.replace(':id', id);
$('#button_cetak').html(url);
```

Comment: number 2 its work, thanks my brothers

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button_cetak').html('<a href="{{routr('+report.pdf+',[$user->nip,'+id+'])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Cetak</a>');
```

This would be the correct way to concatenate.